# Swift 5: How do you perform a selector on an object?

Tags: ios, swift, set, selector, swift-protocols

I am implementing, as an exercise, NSNotificationCenter.
My original data structure for the map that would hold the observers was:

```
protocol CustomObserver : Hashable {
  func receiveNotification(userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]?)
}

//....class declaration and init for CustomNotificationCenter

private var notificationsMap: [String: Set<CustomObservers>] = [:]
```

where the CustomObservers would have a receiveNotification(...) call. However, I found out that I can't have a Set of a Protocol in Swift:

```
// This syntax did not work given the above code blocks.
Set<CustomObserver>
```

After a lot of Stack Overflowing, I couldn't find a graceful solution. All solutions seem to involve:

1. Make an observer protocol.
2. Make a class that conforms to observer protocol.
3. Make all of your observers subclass from the above class.

If anyone has a graceful solution to a Set that doesn't involve making new classes, I'm all ears. Until then...

I decided to try using this data structure instead:

```
private var notificationsMap: [String: [AnyHashable: Selector]] = [:]
```

Whereby I wouldn't rely on a protocol to define the receiveNotification behavior, but I would instead have a selector to call for every object that is subscribed to a notification.

In my post function for the NotificationCenter, I have this code which is supposed to:

1. Find the dictionary associated with the notification's name.
2. Iterate through the dictionary, calling the selector on each object.

```
  func post(name: String, object: Any?, userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]?) {
    if let obsArray = notificationsMap[name] {
      for (object, selector) in obsArray {
        object.performSelector(onMainThread: selector, withObject: nil, waitUntilDone: true)
      }
    }
  }
```

However, on the performSelector line, I get this error:

```
Value of type 'AnyHashable' has no member 'performSelector'
```

So how do I do this? How do I performSelector? Or...how can I make a Set work?

Comment: You would probably need to use `[NSObject: Selector]` since selector dispatch is part of Objective C, not Swift.  I know it is just an exercise, but it doesn't make much sense to try and re-implement Objective-C style `NSNotificationCenter` in Swift.  You could do it in Objective C, or if you wanted the functionality without the exact API, simply store closures - which is much more "Swift"

Comment: `AnyHashable` makes no guarantee you will also satify `NSObjectProtocol` which describes `performSelector` among other things.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you would call it a *graceful solution* but I would use type erasure, it's the same principle used in [AnyCollection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/anycollection) or [AnyPublisher](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/anypublisher):

```swift
class AnyCustomObserver: CustomObserver {
    private let id = UUID() // needed for Hashable conformance
    private let handleNotification: ([AnyHashable: Any]?) -> Void
    
    init(_ observer: any CustomObserver) {
        handleNotification = observer.receiveNotification(userInfo:)
    }
    
    func receiveNotification(userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]?) {
        handleNotification(userInfo)
    }
}

extension AnyCustomObserver: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: AnyCustomObserver, rhs: AnyCustomObserver) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}

extension AnyCustomObserver: Hashable {
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
}
```

Now you can implement your `notificationsMap` property

```
private var notificationsMap: [String: Set<AnyCustomObserver>] = [:]
```

##### Note

For simplicity, I added an UUID to satisfy `Equatable` and `Hashable` requirements but it might better to have and identifier or a name in `CustomObserver`.